# Pass bool value from javascript to c# using invokescript

Tags: c#, javascript, winforms, browser

I have this code:

```
private void frmMain_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isEditing = (bool)webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("isEditing");

        MessageBox.Show("End");
        e.Cancel = false;
    }
```

The program doesn't close, neither does it get to `MessageBox.Show("End");` Taking out the line `bool isEditing = (bool)webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("isEditing");` makes it work (and the program exits).

`isEditing` is a javascript function which looks like this:

```
function isEditing(){ return editing; } // editing being either true or false
```

I'm not aware of how to get any error messages via a debug console in c# (although if someone wants to point me in the right direction then I can come back and post it).

What I ultimately want to do is to have a script that stops the form from closing if i'm editing in my web browser. (But I can't seem to get as far as the first line!)

Is what I'm doing wrong? And if so, then whats wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: i think ur return type is not getting captured correctly. Why dont u try getting the type by function GetType to see if boolean value is returned. You can explicitly convert using Convert.ToBool(webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("isEditing")) to check if its returning something.

Comment: This may give u some useful info -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be9zzz62.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Note that if the `InvokeScript()` call throws an exception (for example, if `isEditing` doesn't exist), the exception will be caught by the form and the close request aborted.

This may explain why your code never gets to `MessageBox.Show("End");` and doesn't close the form.

You should be able to see any caught Exception information in the Output Window in Visual Studio, or you can force Visual Studio to break on any exception by going to the `Debug->Exceptions` menu and checking the Common Language Runtime Exceptions option.